# ob_start() works fine on local but not on server

Tags: php

I am making an application where I use ob_start() function. Its works fine on my local machine, but when I launch it on online server, this doesn't work. No error displayed, just empty page is displayed. Have to do any configuration on server? Please help me. Thanks
my code is as below

```
ob_start();
include("text.php");
$data = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Enable error reporting first.

Comment: error reporting is enabled already

Comment: Check for any spaces at starting or at the end of file.

Comment: What does that mean "it does not work"?

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error log file? If output buffering is on, you won't see the error messages in the web page.

Comment: Please show your actual code. `ob_start()` isn't supposed to produce any output, it stops output. The output doesn't come until you call something like `ob_end_flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to below link

have you checked php configuration file php.ini ?

[ob_start() and ob_flush() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837006/ob-start-and-ob-flush-doesnt-work)

Please check if output_buffering has set value and it is not set as off.