# Flush not working

Tags: php, flush

I'm trying to display realtime php process output using this code below, but it doesn't work, it doesn't show the process in realtime, it only displays the final output at once

```
echo "Start...";

for ($i = 0; $i<20; $i++){
    echo $i;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
 }

echo "Done!";
ob_end_flush();
exit;
```

Comment: By final output do you mean it shows everything (all the numbers) at once?

Comment: check this, your answer lies here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837006/ob-start-and-ob-flush-doesnt-work

Comment: @A-2-A it doesn't work :/

Comment: By Chance you use `IIS?`: http://php.net/manual/de/function.flush.php#113360

Answer (score 0):

Flush is on the `PHP` side. However, some webservers have their own output cache.

---

The `IIS` for example has the [`ResponseBufferLimit`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.flush.php#113360) option.

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:handlers "/[name='PHP_via_FastCGI'].ResponseBufferLimit:0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers nowdays wont display the page until they have all the initial DOM content (excluding separate resources like images etc) unless the page is very large. I think it is to ensure all the css rules are present before displaying anything. [Heres what the manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't clear. I thought you were running PHP directly.
If you're running PHP through a browser this wouldn't work.
PHP through a browser would run the entire program and then server the page. It doesn't have any facilities for updating the HTML.
You typically use ajax to do that.

I assume your code snippet actually looked like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
   echo "My first PHP script!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to do this in PHP, you have to figure out how to run it directly. Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/9520125/5276890.